Why can't $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ be linearly-ordered without Axiom of Choice?
This Question has an answer which is the only source that I can find about how $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be linearly ordered. I couldn't manage to open either of the source links provided in the answer. Could someone please explain why $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ can only be linearly ordered with the Axiom of Choice in a way that is understandable to a graduate with set theory knowledge?

The source is Sur une proposition qui entraîne l'existence des ensembles non mesurables by Sierpiński. There is a link to it here, of course in French

Note that the answer doesn't say that in the absence of AC you can never linearly order $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$, but that its consistent with ZF that you can't linearly order $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$

See this answer
